# Show perpendicular symbol on graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

For an example I have two lines:

```
Line[{a,b}],
Line[{a,c}]
```

Is there any easy way to display visual (red symbols) that the angle between these lines are 90°
[image: example]

Comment: Have you took a look at the Graphics Tools palette? You can type a `\[RightAngle]` symbol to annotate your graph

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the following:

```
perp[pt_, angle_:0, size_:Offset[10]]:=With[
    {
    h = Replace[size,
        {
        Offset[s_]->(Offset[s #, pt]&),
        Scaled[s_]->(Scaled[s #, pt]&),
        ImageScaled[s_]->(ImageScaled[s #, pt]&),
        s_->(pt + s #&)
        }
    ]
    },

    Rotate[Line[{h[{0,1}], h[{1,1}], h[{1,0}]}], angle, pt]
]
```

This function creates the desired [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line) object in the first quadrant. The optional second argument can be used to rotate the "symbol", and the optional third argument controls the size. Here is an example:

```
Graphics[{Line[{{0,1}, {0,0}, {-1,0}}], {Red, perp[{0, 0}, Pi/2, Scaled[.25]]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice sollution. But what if Lines could be dynamically adjusted. How to get right angle to rotate this "sign". Simple sketch to visualize what I mean - https://i.imgur.com/CeeL0gD.png

Comment: @Mindau I don't understand the question, but perhaps the following helps `Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
  Red, perp[{0, 0}], Blue, perp[{1, 0}, Pi/2, .25], Green, 
  perp[{1, 1}, Pi, ImageScaled[.1]], Orange, 
  perp[{0, 1}, 3 Pi/2, Offset[20]]}]`